# Angular 2 component less routing, executing whatever logic when particular URL is matched and redirect further

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm using email service provider to which backend (microservice arhitecture) is sending various details that are needed to populate email dynamically. One of those details are `links` such as `Deposit here` link within an email where, when customer clicks on it he should be redirected to app directly to deposit page.

How actual link looks like for example is:
 `my-app.com/deposit?accountId=1&customerId=10&something=30`

What data is passed to email service provider is:
`my-app.com/email-redirects?page=deposit`

The reason why I don't want that backend constructs actual link is because of changes, if I change link on frontend I need to change backend as well. Besides that for many links service that is doing this does not have needed info (query parameters) so this service would need to call other services to get needed info. Frontend should handle this easier.

What I'm trying to do is something like **component-less** routing, where when `path` is
 `email-redirects` some piece of logic based on `page` query parameter should be executed which will create actual link `my-app.com/deposit?accountId=1&customerId=10&something=30`

The goal of this is that frontend should be able to construct complete actual url based on `page` parameter calling backend if it needs any additional info such as `accountId`, `customerId`, `something`. As soon as it creates the actual link, logic should just redirect customer to actual url and appropriate component will be rendered. Anyway to achieve component-less routing?

Comment: As an aside, th url seems inviting to phishing and the like. Perhaps you can create a hashed link on the backend first and then reload/resolve it later on usage? Even with a redirect? So that your links look like this: my-app.com/deposit-link/<some meaningless hash>. So then angular first loads the actual values from backend (`/rest/something/<the hash again>`) and the backend gives it the account id, customer id , values, and angular redirects or otherwise itself to this page. Or even your backend it could read the proper values from db and redirect you to the proper angular url like above.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `UrlMatcher`. https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

Create a custom `UrlMatcher` for your `email-redirects` path, and if it matches, return a new `UrlSegment` with the `deposit?accountId=1&customerId=10&something=30` info in it. This new route will be passed to the child router where you will be able to do whatever you want with it.

Comment: As it seems `path` and `matcher` cannot be used together. If i leave just `matcher` i get following error: `One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren`

Comment: can you provide small example?