# How to configure angular-cli/webpack to create separate bundle of each feature module(Angular 4)

Tags: angular, webpack

How to Configure Angular-cli or Webpack to create separate bundle of each feature module(Angular 4) without **routing**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure CLI or webpack. Just use lazy loading for your app routes. Your app-routing.module.ts could look like

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: '../modules/feature/feature.module#FeatrueModule' }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In your app.module.ts just import `AppRoutingModule` without importing `FeatureModule` and you should go fine. Your prod build output should contain e.g. the following files

- index.html
- inline.randomstring.bundle.js (main, polyfills and so on)
- and for each lazy loaded module a

  - 0.randomstring.chunk.js
  - 1.randomstring.chunk.js
  - ...

Comment: Thanks @ngfelixl,but how would i achieve it without routing lazy loading

Comment: Additionaly importing FeatureModule in your AppModule creates a separate file for your module but directly loads it.

Comment: @NMR Why would you want different bundles for each module if you're not lazy loading?

Comment: @Narm ,I am thinking to create separate module for each user role type in my application and bundle separately( through webpack.config),would download on demand after login on basis of user role type..This how would be able to download only user specific code at client machine

Comment: Ok makes sense and is a common use case. What you're describing is lazy loading features on demand. In which case @ngfelixl has the correct answer. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: @ngfelixl How do you i load these bundles created dynamically,as i have to load these bundle and route will remain same

Comment: @NMR These bundles get loaded dynamically as you access the routes. E.g. you have an admin section excluded in a feature module accessible by '/admin' route, similar as described above, then the bundle gets loaded only if you hit '/admin' or any subroutes.

Comment: @ngfelixl Yes,but i want to load them under same route lets say post login url dashboard.so different module under dashboard url based on user role

Comment: @NMR Then why do you need lazy loading? Just load it with your AppModule as it seems to load your dashboard, login etc. as well.

Comment: @ngfelixl I have multiple module ,one for each user role type..if loads with AppModule,all user role type module will be downloaded on client machine which i want to avoid

Comment: @NMR what do these user role type modules do? Displaying some kind of batch or is it more complicated?

Comment: @NMR This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693104/angular-2-component-less-routing-executing-whatever-logic-when-particular-url-i) maybe also interesting for you

Comment: @ngfelixl these modules will have website feature and functionality,different business rules,just like if i buy premium license of linked in